# Why cat date.txt does not show any output

Tags: 18.04

```
syed@Emad-World:~$ date | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 > date.txt | cat date.txt
syed@Emad-World:~$
```

Comment: Write it like `date | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 > date.txt && cat date.txt`

Answer (score 3):

The shell's pipe (`|`) construct is for connecting the standard output of one process to the standard input of another.

In your case, you are redirecting standard output of the `cut` command to a file (`> date.txt`), and not reading standard input at all (since you pass a filename argument, `date.txt`, to the `cat` command). Appropriate shell conjunctions in this case are:

- `&&` in which `cat date.txt` will be executed conditionally, depending on the successful exit status of previous commands in the pipeline

or

- `;` in which case `cat date.txt` will be executed unconditionally

In this case, `&&` is probably more appropriate (we won't try to read from `date.txt` if we were unable to write to it for example). So

```
date | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 > date.txt && cat date.txt
```

Unless you're just playing with pipes, you can avoid the `cut` by telling `date` to output only the abbreviated day name directly:

```
date +%a > date.txt && cat date.txt
```

---

You might wonder why `date | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 > date.txt | cat date.txt` doesn't work anyhow - since it's syntactically correct. The reason for this is that you can't rely on the order of execution of the LHS and RHS of a pipe - so `cat date.txt` is as likely as not to be executed before the output of the date command has been written to it.

- [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run)

Answer (score 2):

It's expected behavior when you pipe nothing.

```
$ date | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 > date.txt | cat date.txt
$
```

Date returns a string, which you chop up and then write one word into a newfile. Creating a newfile has no output on STDOUT, so nothing gets piped to cat.